# ASP.NET CodeBehind System.Web.UI.Control.Controls returns one element

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have page.aspx, the top line of that is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs" Inherits="className"%>
```

This is the first time I have attempted an aspx (or any) web page.

I think I need a `runat="server"` somewhere in the page, I have put that into the body HTML tag as there are multiple inputs (a better way to do that would also be welcome, though not my main question)

```
<body runat="server" id="body">
```

The c# I have on page.aspx.cs is below

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class className : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    HtmlGenericControl body = FindControl("body") as HtmlGenericControl;

        if (body != null)
        {
            foreach (Control contr in body.Controls)
            {
                 Debug.WriteLine(contr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //comment
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to use Control.FindControl(ID) so I resorted to the above to try and find *any* control.
In the instance contained in the C# foreach loop, the `contr` list element has at `Text` property containing as a string, what I would have expected to be contained in the Controls collection. Using the exact code above the `Text` property contains everything inside the 'body' tag as a string.

As this is my first time posting, I am sure to have got things wrong, so please tell me if more information is needed.

Having replaced the find method for the body element with

```
HtmlGenericControl body = FindControl("body") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

And with the following aspx file contents

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JSPCheck.aspx.cs" Inherits="JSPCheckForm"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="html">
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js" > </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.js" > </script>

        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/bootstrap.js" > </script>
        <link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" > </script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <title>Page</title>

    </head>
    <body runat="server" id="body">

        <p id="para1">test paragraph</p>

        <h3 id="h31">test header</h3>


        <form method="post" id="mainform">
            <!-- "Serial Number" row -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="SerialNumber" class="control-label" >Serial Number</label>
                <!-- Entry box -->
                <input class="form-control" name="SerialNumber" value="" id="SerialNumber" type="text"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="command1" value="&nbsp;" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit1"> Verify </button>
            </div>
        </form>            
    </body>
</html>
```

The Debug prints the following single line to the console

```
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
```

and at that debug the `contr` has the property `Text`

```
"\r\n        \r\n        <p id=\"para1\">test paragraph</p>\r\n\r\n        <h3 id=\"h31\">test header</h3>\r\n\r\n\r\n        <form method=\"post\" id=\"mainform\">\r\n            <!-- \"Serial Number\" row -->\r\n            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n                <label for=\"SerialNumber\" class=\"control-label\" >Serial Number</label>\r\n                <!-- Entry box -->\r\n                <input class=\"form-control\" name=\"SerialNumber\" value=\"\" id=\"SerialNumber\" type=\"text\"/>\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n                <button type=\"submit\" name=\"command1\" value=\"&nbsp;\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" id=\"Submit1\"> Verify </button>\r\n            </div>\r\n        </form>\r\n        \r\n   "
```

and an ID of `ctl00`

Additional testing has determined that if I move the `runat="server"` around, I can `FindControl` that element and that element only.

Comment: If you want to find any control inside your body you can directly use body.Controls instead of Control.FindControl. Have you tried that?

Comment: using `body.Controls` gives "The name 'body' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: It should resolve as you set your body element's id as body with runat server

Comment: This is what I get in the page.aspx.cs file, not sure what else i could do about that [link](https://i.imgur.com/hmend51.png)

Comment: what's id of your body element? It should be on the same page.

Comment: I am using `CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs"` so they are on different pages

Comment: @ArunKumar I have solved the issues I was having, and have added them to the answer I have given.

Answer (score 0):

So for the idiots like me, using `CodeBehind` and trying to get elements. As far as I can tell every element you want to *find* must have a `runat="server"` within the tag, and not have one `runat="server"` for the whole page.

And trying to use the element id's directly as objects was not working because I did not have an `.aspx.designer.cs` file. In visual studio 2017 the option to correct this "Convert to Web Application" is located in the "Project" dropdown menu when a convertable `.aspx` file is selected.